# Will this code run from an inherited EF constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Imagine we have two DbContexts that inherit from EF DbContext as such:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace myproject.Models
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Database.CommandTimeout = Config.DatabaseCommandTimeout;
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        }

        public MyContext() : this("name=MyDbContextConnectionString") { }
    }
    
    public class MyContext2ReadOnly : MyContext
    { 
        public MyContext2ReadOnly() : base("MyDbContextConnectionStringReadOnly")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now imagine we create an instance of `MyContext2ReadOnly()`.
My question is - will the following line `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`  from the parent constructor be valid, or do I have to call it again in the `MyContext2ReadOnly()` constructor as such(?):

```
 public class MyContext2ReadOnly : MyContext
{ 
    public MyContext2ReadOnly() : base("MyDbContextConnectionStringReadOnly")
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<MyContext2ReadOnly>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. your code won't compile in efcore6, which version of ef are you using? 2. note `Base` should be `base`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the constructor `MyContext2ReadOnly()`, then step through the code to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think `DbContext` is not special when handling inheritance and constructor. So just have a test. I will define a `Db` to replace `DbContext`.

```cs
    public class Db
    {
        public Db(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Db {s}");
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : Db
    {
        public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MyContext {nameOrConnectionString}");
        }

        public MyContext() : this("name=MyDbContextConnectionString") { }
    }

    public class MyContext2ReadOnly : MyContext
    {
        public MyContext2ReadOnly() : base("MyDbContextConnectionStringReadOnly")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MyContext2ReadOnly");
        }
    }
```

```cs
//in main
MyContext2ReadOnly myContext2ReadOnly = new MyContext2ReadOnly();
//output
Db MyDbContextConnectionStringReadOnly
MyContext MyDbContextConnectionStringReadOnly
MyContext2ReadOnly
```

It proves everything in `MyContext` constructor are called.